# buffering.rb:205:in `sysread_nonblock': Operation timed out (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)

Tags: ios, ruby, flutter, fastlane

When I am using this fastlane(`v2.206.2`) script in github actions to publish the flutter project to https://www.pgyer.com/:

```
 - name: Deploy to TestFlight/PGY
    run: |
      cd ./ios
      bundle exec fastlane beta
    env:
      FLUTTER_ROOT: ${{ secrets.FLUTTER_ROOT }}
      APPLE_ID: ${{ secrets.APPLE_ID }}
      GIT_URL: ${{ secrets.GIT_URL }}
      PGY_USER_KEY: ${{ secrets.PGY_USER_KEY }}
      PGY_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.PGY_API_KEY }}
      TEAM_ID: ${{ secrets.TEAM_ID }}
      ITC_TEAM_ID: ${{ secrets.ITC_TEAM_ID }}
      FASTLANE_USER: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_USER }}
      FASTLANE_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_PASSWORD }}
      FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD }}
      FASTLANE_SESSION: ${{ secrets.FASTLANE_SESSION }}
      MATCH_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MATCH_PASSWORD }}
      MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME: ${{ secrets.MATCH_KEYCHAIN_NAME }}
      MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}
      DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS: ${{ secrets.DELIVER_ITMSTRANSPORTER_ADDITIONAL_UPLOAD_PARAMETERS }}
```

shows error like this:

```
[16:01:53]: Operation timed out

+------+------------------+-------------+
|           fastlane summary            |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action           | Time (in s) |
+------+------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform | 0           |
| 2    | xcode_select     | 0           |
| 3    | is_ci            | 0           |
| 4    | create_keychain  | 0           |
| 5    | is_ci            | 0           |
| 6    | match            | 2           |
| 7    | build_app        | 142         |
| 8    | gym              | 102         |
|    | pgyer            | 1419        |
+------+------------------+-------------+

[16:01:53]: fastlane finished with errors

Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...

➡️  [iTunes Transporter]: Read Timed Out - unable to upload app to TestFlight
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/16892 [closed] 78 
bundler: failed to load command: fastlane (/Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/bin/fastlane)
    a week ago

➡️   iTMSTransporter fails when uploading to store.
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/openssl/buffering.rb:205:in `sysread_nonblock': \e[31m[!] Operation timed out\e[0m (Faraday::TimeoutError)
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/18619 [closed] 3 
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/openssl/buffering.rb:205:in `read_nonblock'
    29 Jun 2021
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/protocol.rb:212:in `rbuf_fill'

    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/protocol.rb:193:in `readuntil'
➡️  Fastlane hangs on Waiting for the build to show up in the build list when distributing to external group
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/protocol.rb:203:in `readline'
    https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/15511 [closed] 20 
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http/response.rb:42:in `read_status_line'
    18 Jul 2020
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http/response.rb:31:in `read_new'

    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:1557:in `block in transport_request'
and 37 more at: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/search?q=Operation%20timed%20out&type=Issues&utf8=✓
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:1548:in `catch'

    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:1548:in `transport_request'
  You can ⌘ + double-click on links to open them directly in your browser.
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:1521:in `request'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:152:in `block in request_via_request_method'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:960:in `start'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:146:in `request_via_request_method'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:131:in `request_with_wrapped_block'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:122:in `perform_request'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:66:in `block in call'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-1.10.2/lib/faraday/adapter.rb:50:in `connection'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:64:in `call'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday_middleware-1.2.0/lib/faraday_middleware/response_middleware.rb:36:in `call'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-1.10.2/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:25:in `call'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-multipart-1.0.4/lib/faraday/multipart/middleware.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-1.10.2/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:154:in `build_response'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-1.10.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:516:in `run_request'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-1.10.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:283:in `post'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-plugin-pgyer-0.2.3/lib/fastlane/plugin/pgyer/actions/pgyer_action.rb:106:in `run'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:263:in `block (2 levels) in execute_action'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:69:in `execute_action'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:255:in `block in execute_action'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `chdir'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `execute_action'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:157:in `trigger_action_by_name'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:159:in `method_missing'
    from Fastfile:72:in `block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in `block in execute'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `chdir'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `execute'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:47:in `cruise_lane'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:36:in `handle'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:110:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:187:in `call'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:157:in `run'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/runner.rb:444:in `run_active_command'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:124:in `run!'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/delegates.rb:18:in `run!'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:354:in `run'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:43:in `start'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:123:in `take_off'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/bin/fastlane:25:in `load'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/bin/fastlane:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/cli.rb:485:in `exec'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/exe/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:120:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/exe/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/openssl/buffering.rb:205:in `sysread_nonblock': Operation timed out (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/openssl/buffering.rb:205:in `read_nonblock'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/protocol.rb:212:in `rbuf_fill'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/protocol.rb:193:in `readuntil'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/protocol.rb:203:in `readline'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http/response.rb:42:in `read_status_line'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http/response.rb:31:in `read_new'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:1557:in `block in transport_request'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:1548:in `catch'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:1548:in `transport_request'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:1521:in `request'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:152:in `block in request_via_request_method'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby@3.0/3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/net/http.rb:960:in `start'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:146:in `request_via_request_method'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:131:in `request_with_wrapped_block'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:122:in `perform_request'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:66:in `block in call'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-1.10.2/lib/faraday/adapter.rb:50:in `connection'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-net_http-1.0.1/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:64:in `call'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday_middleware-1.2.0/lib/faraday_middleware/response_middleware.rb:36:in `call'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-1.10.2/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:25:in `call'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-multipart-1.0.4/lib/faraday/multipart/middleware.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-1.10.2/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:154:in `build_response'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-1.10.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:516:in `run_request'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/faraday-1.10.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:283:in `post'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-plugin-pgyer-0.2.3/lib/fastlane/plugin/pgyer/actions/pgyer_action.rb:106:in `run'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:263:in `block (2 levels) in execute_action'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/actions/actions_helper.rb:69:in `execute_action'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:255:in `block in execute_action'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `chdir'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:229:in `execute_action'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:157:in `trigger_action_by_name'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/fast_file.rb:159:in `method_missing'
    from Fastfile:72:in `block (2 levels) in parsing_binding'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane.rb:33:in `call'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:49:in `block in execute'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `chdir'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/runner.rb:45:in `execute'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/lane_manager.rb:47:in `cruise_lane'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb:36:in `handle'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:110:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:187:in `call'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/command.rb:157:in `run'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/runner.rb:444:in `run_active_command'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:124:in `run!'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/commander-4.6.0/lib/commander/delegates.rb:18:in `run!'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:354:in `run'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:43:in `start'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:123:in `take_off'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/gems/fastlane-2.209.1/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/bin/fastlane:25:in `load'
    from /Users/runner/work/cruise-open/cruise-open/ios/vendor/cache/ruby/3.0.0/bin/fastlane:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:58:in `kernel_load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:23:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/cli.rb:485:in `exec'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/cli.rb:31:in `dispatch'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:485:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/cli.rb:25:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/exe/bundle:48:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:120:in `with_friendly_errors'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bundler-2.3.20/exe/bundle:36:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

what should I do to fixed this problem? this is the pyer fastfile config which was followed the manual from here https://github.com/shishirui/fastlane-plugin-pgyer:

```
    gym
    pgyer(
        api_key: ENV['PGY_API_KEY']
    )
```